# Codeigniter SQL Server group_by() function Active record giving me a error

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, activerecord, group-by, codeigniter-3

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmw3t.jpg)

```
function getDeniedListFromNextLevel() {

    return $this->db->select('files.client_name,multiple_files.idmultiple_files,files.idfiles,files.id_multiple_files')->join('file_status', 'file_status.idfiles=files.id_multiple_files')->join('level','level.level=file_status.on_level')->join('file_transaction', 'file_transaction.idfile_transaction=file_status.id_last_transaction')->join('multiple_files','files.id_multiple_files=multiple_files.idmultiple_files')->where('file_status.on_level < ', 0)->group_by('idmultiple_files')->get('files')->result_array();
}
```

> if I exclude group_by() then it works well what might be the reason any one here who can help me to get rid of this :(

Comment: Error Number: 42000/8120

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column 'files.client_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: i think you are missing the table name in group_by clause

Answer (score 1):

i think you are missing the table name in group_by clause

Comment: Already done this but not works .it still gives me the same message

Comment: i think that you should use MAX,SUM where you need to group the column
eg:
a   value
--------
1   val
1   val2
1   val3
2   val4
2   val5

group_by(a) now which value will be accessed by a is not defined
so you can use ** SELECT MAX(value) group_by((a))**

Answer (score 0):

Do The following change,it might work

->group_by('multiple_files.idmultiple_files')

Comment: I think, it will very helpful if you mention the tables structure, it will very specific and helpful with that. for giving solution.